# Folders in VS code

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio, visual-studio-code, error-handling

If I have a .py (called p.py) folder where I have my code and I want to open a file which is a .json (called j.json) file and I have opened it as a folder next to the p.py folder. I want to read from the j.json make it a dictionary. It does not seem to work with this :

```
import json
with open("j.json") as f:
    data = json.load(f)
```

output: `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `p.py` and `j.json` are at the same level, we can directly quote it as its name instead of its absolute path:

[image]

Turn to file explorer, **View** -> Select **File name extensions**, to check if the name of `j.json` is right, or we can say, to check if `j.json` exists:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try the full path directory instead of just your file name. But you should put an r before the string. E.g.

```
with open(r'path_to_file/j.json') as f: 
    data = json.load(f)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you specify a path (that is not absolute) it is relative to the directory you are executing Python in

Let's say I'm in my Terminal at directory C:/Users/Mathias/Desktop and I execute the following code with Python

```py
with open("veryimportant.json", "r") as file:
   for line in file:
       print(line)
```

"veryimportant.json" will be relative to my working directory (C:/Users/Mathias/Desktop) so the absolute path will be C:/Users/Mathias/Desktop/veryimportant.json

## So what can you do?

You have the following options.

### Option 1

Move the j.json file to the same directory as your p.py file

### Option 2

Refer to j.json with the absolute path (looks something like this "C:/path/to/file.json" with your drive letter first)